# Print image field with multiple entries from field in twig template

Tags: theming, 8, media

I have a twig template for a custom content type. And it is able to render most fields just fine, but I am unable to print an image field with multiple images.

node--mycontenttype.html.twig contains

```
{{ content.field_mytitle }}
{{ content.field_myheaderimage }}
<div class="row expanded">
    {% for galleryimage in content.field_gallery_images %}
           <div class="gallery-image-item"> {{ galleryimage }} </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

content.field_mytitle and content._field_myheaderimage outputs the title and image just fine. But when I use the for loop

```
    {% for galleryimage in content.field_gallery_images %}
           <div class="gallery-image-item"> {{ galleryimage }} </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I receive an error

```
Exception: Object of type Drupal\node\Entity\Node cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line 443 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php).
```

When I just use

```
{{ content.field_gallery_images }}
```

It's able to output each image, but this does not allow me to wrap each item in divs and add content to each one.

Comment: The answer from @4k4 below has many advantages, but for your sanity, replacing: content.field_gallery_images with node.field_gallery_images in your twig 'for' loop would have given you each image entity in the loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Print the image field in the node template like any other field:

```
{{ content.field_gallery_images }}
```

And then use a field twig to loop through multiple field items:

**field--field-gallery-images.html.twig**

```
<div class="row expanded">
  {% for item in items %}
    <div class="gallery-image-item">{{ item.content }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

On D8 I was able to make a foreach loop on my images in a way to generate a carousel.

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    {% for i in 0..content.field_accueil_image_slide|length %}
     {%if content.field_accueil_image_slide[i]['#item'].entity.uri.value != "" and content.field_accueil_image_slide[i]['#item'].entity.uri.value is not empty %}
        <div class="item {{ (i == 0) ? 'active' : '' }}" style="">{{ content.field_accueil_image_slide[i]}}</div>
     {%endif%}
    {%endfor%}
  </div>
```

Comment: Huge help thanks. Why do drupal when you can figure out the rabbit hole in twig? :D

Comment: I this for the node.html.twig? or field.html.twig?

Comment: @cwiggo, it's not the cleaner way but yes :)

Comment: @ShakilAhmad in this case it is in the node twig because you access to a the content field. But in Drupal you could do this update in multiple ways,..